# repository for suse version of linux

Tags: opensuse, suse

Is there a command repository for Suse Linux where we can install a library and all its ?dependencies?

I recently I need to install an R-base program which needed libgfortran library and this library needed bunch of dependency and so forth. It became a nightmare to install the whole thing, I am still not finished.

Since I am very new to this OS, I was curious if there is a common repository for all common libraries for SUSe. I'd appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 1):

I think every major distro has an official set of repos - here is the OpenSuse repo

http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/

After that, there are lots of projects that come out of other extra repos - see here http://en.opensuse.org/Additional_package_repositories

Comment: thank you for your answer. Would this repository have libgfortran library and dependencies? would this be the right syntax to create the repo? zypper addrepo -fG http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/

Comment: Google is my friend and now yours. See this article - http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/suse/README.html and also this page - http://software.opensuse.org/package/R-base. All dependencies should be automatically installed - I have not tried this, but that's what package managers like yum and zypper are built to do.